# How to invoke administrator command prompt from batch script without having to enter password

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to automate a windows service installation task using an installUtil command embedded in a .bat file. The OS I have is Windows 2012 Server standard edition.

Whenever I do it manually, I need to invoke the administrator command prompt to run the InstallUtil command. Even though my login account has administrative privileges, when I invoke a command prompt, change path to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319", and then run the command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>InstallUtil "Path of my executables"
```

I am met with an error message saying "The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed"

To get around the above error, I right-click on "Command Prompt" under "Windows System", and choose "Run as Administrator", this invokes the administrator command prompt, i.e., the one captioned "Administrator: Command Prompt". The windows service installs just fine when I run the above InstallUtil command on this prompt. **I do not need to enter the administrator password in order to invoke the administrator command prompt in this manner** and run commands on it.

Now I am trying to automate the same process as above using a .bat file.

In the .bat file, I try entering the following command:

```
InstallUtil /runas /user:MyMachine\Administrator
```

But when I run the batch file (both by double clicking and using the 'Run as Administrator' option), I am prompted for the administrator password. I try supplying various options to the InstallUtil command, such as /nouac, /noprofile, /env, etc., but it prompts me for the administrator password each time, which I don't have.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible you cant grant a file admin privileges automatically. If this was possible then it would defeat the object of UAC. And this would allow all kinds of vulnerability's to open up.

Comment: If not this way then is there any other way to automate the installation of a windows service? That's my primary objective here. I do not really wish to override UAC.

Comment: Try looking at this: https://octopusdeploy.com/automated-deployments/windows-service-deployment

Comment: Isn't there any way I could do it without using any third party tools? I mean, using batch scripts or something like that?

Comment: Then how are windows services deployed incrementally?

Comment: I am not sure how it does it.

Comment: RunAs doesn't elevate you. Set the compatability on your program to runasadmin.

Comment: Ok, what I am actually trying to achieve through all this circus is to achieve an incremental build of a windows service. Am I on the wrong track? If this approach of uninstalling/reinstalling the service from the administrator command prompt is not the right way to do it, could someone please point me to the right way?

Comment: RunAs doesn't elevate you. Set the compatability on your program to runasadmin is simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is vbscript using the shell elevation verb RUNAS to elevate itself.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " " & sParms, , "runas", 1
Msgbox "error is " & err.number & " " & err.description
```

This is a script that allows you to list verbs for a file or execute verbs for a file.

```
HelpMsg = vbcrlf & "  ShVerb" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  David Candy 2014" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf & "    ShVerb <filename> [verb]" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator" & vbcrlf & "  of the menu work when used this way" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf 
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running" & vbcrlf & "  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying" & vbcrlf & "  a message box." 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag = WScript.Arguments 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Ag.count = 0 then 
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - No file specified"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    Else If Ag.count = 1 then 
        If LCase(Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/")) = "/h" or Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/") = "/?" then 
            wscript.echo HelpMsg 
            wscript.quit
        End If
    ElseIf Ag.count > 2 then 
        wscript.echo vbcrlf & "  ShVerb - To many parameters" & vbcrlf & "  Use quotes around filenames and verbs containing spaces"  & vbcrlf
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    If fso.DriveExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
'       Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.self
        msgbox ag(0)
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    ElseIf fso.fileExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    Else
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - " & Ag(0) & " not found"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    Set objVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs

    'If only one argument list verbs for that item

    If Ag.count = 1 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If len(cmd) <> 0 then CmdList = CmdList & vbcrlf & replace(cmd.name, "&", "") 
        Next
        wscript.echo mid(CmdList, 2)

    'If two arguments do verbs for that item

    ElseIf Ag.count = 2 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If lcase(replace(cmd, "&", "")) = LCase(Ag(1)) then 
                wscript.echo Cmd.doit 
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    'Properties is special cased. Script has to stay running for Properties dialog to show.
        If Lcase(Ag(1)) = "properties" then
            WSHShell.AppActivate(ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties")
            msgbox "This message box has to stay open to keep the " & ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties dialog open."
        End If  
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Forgive my naivette, but where do I write/execute this script? Is it a one time thing that makes permanent changes, or do I need to execute it everytime I have to install a service? Please advise.

Comment: Copy it into a file called ShVerb.vbs. To use either (for output via message boxes) shverb file verb or (for output to a command prompt window) cscript //nologo shverb file verb. Run without parameters for help.